# adding a twitter share button to my site

Tags: javascript, php, button, twitter

I am thinking of adding a twitter share button to my site, I got the code from [here](https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons), but the problem is that button appears with an image of a bird and the text "tweet", is there a way to have my own button, just want to have a div size 16*16px with img of  a bird that does the same thing as the twitter button. for example see how this [site](http://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/columnist/baig/2014/09/16/edbaig-review-sizing-up-iphone6-6plus/15718565/) does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As easy as this:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share">Add your 16x16px image here</a>


<a href="https://twitter.com/share?hashtags=awesome,sharing&text=My Page Title or Something Else to share&via=MyTwitterHandle"><img src="/my_custom_twitter_image.png" title="Share this page on Twitter" /></a>
```

This will tweet the "text" part using the "tags" listed attribute the tweet to MyTwitterHandle and show my_custom_twitter_image and the link image.

See https://snipt.net/huskie/custom-twitter-share-link/

Answer (score 0):

Is there is any predefined button of twitter share like facebook share button

`<iframe src='https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&layout=button_count&size=large&width=110&height=28&appId' width='110' height='28' style={{ border: "none", overflow: "hidden" }} scrolling='no' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen='true' allow='autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share' title='fbbtn' ></iframe>`